# WPF XAML Static Resource Style is only applied to one item

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

So I don't understand how this happens but I defined a button style in a resource dictionary and load that dictionary in the `Windows.Resources`.

But it"s not applied to all the buttons I want to only to the last element.

The style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="FolderOpenBtn">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Margin="0,0,2,0">
                    <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <DrawingBrush>
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M0,0L16,0 16,16 0,16z" />
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M0,2.9688L0,11.9688C0,12.5858 0.227,13.0718 0.57,13.4038 1.14,13.9478 2,13.9688 2,13.9688L13.677,13.9688 16,8.1648 16,6.9688 15,6.9688 15,4.9688C15,3.6698,13.97,2.9688,13,2.9688L10.116,2.9688 9.116,0.9688 2,0.9688C1.005,0.9688,0,1.6658,0,2.9688" />
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M2,3L8,3 9,5 13,5 13,8 4,8 2,13z" />
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF424242" Geometry="F1M1,3L1,12C1,12.97,1.94,12.984,1.997,12.984L2,12.984 2,3 8,3 9,5 13,5 13,8 4,8 2,13 13,13 15,8 14,8 14,5C14,4,12.764,4,13,4L9.5,4 8.5,2 2,2C2,2,1,2,1,3" />
                                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Text="Select..." />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Loading the dictionaries:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/templates/Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/templates/DatabaseTabItem.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/templates/SatzartTabItem.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

And applying the style to two buttons:

*Button 1*:

```
<Button x:Name="ClassPathSelectBtn" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="70" Width="Auto" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Click="BtnSelectPath_Click" Background="#e3e3e3" Style="{StaticResource FolderOpenBtn}" />
```

*Button 2*:

```
<Button x:Name="reportPathSelectBtn" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" MinWidth="70" Width="Auto" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   Click="BtnSelectPath_Click" Background="#e3e3e3" Style="{StaticResource FolderOpenBtn}"/>
```

The result looks like this however:
[image: two buttons only one of them with the style applied]

Please ignore the blue hover effect.

Can you please help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a UI element in the Style, applied to the Button's Content.

Since the Style and hence also the UI element is shared, there is only once instance of it. However, a single UI element can only be shown once, i.e. can only have a single parent element. You may  get around this by setting the `x:Shared` attribute of the Style to false:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="FolderOpenBtn" x:Shared="False">
    ...
<Style>
```

---

Instead of directly creating a UI element by assigning the Button's Content, you may better set the ContentTemplate property:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="FolderOpenBtn">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Select..."/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,2,0">
                        ...
                    </Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

That would also allow to easily replace the text, just by setting a Button's Content to some other value than the default `"Select..."`.